# How to resize image in canvas proportionately with respect to width in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

The minimum `width` of the image should be `300` and the height should get scaled proportionately with respect to width.

Suppose the user uploads image size of `5ooX850`, I will use

```
                Img.set({
                    scaleX: 300 / Img.width,
                });
```

But how to scale image `height` with respect to `width`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scale Y by the same ratio used to scale X

```
let scale = 300 / Img.width;

Img.set({
    scaleX: scale,
    scaleY: scale
});
```

With your example of `500 x 850`, both X and Y would be `3/5` of their original measurements.

Answer (score 6):

Set in image object

```
/*scaleToWidth(value, absolute)*/
Img.scaleToWidth(300, false);
```

[this is the link for doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToWidth)